# CSS loading after jQuery

Tags: css

I have checked similar topics but did not find a satisfactory answer. [My website](http://www.canay-tv.net/) is very long in height so it takes long to load. I have a fixed div which should only appear when user scrolls until the buttom. But the hidden div appears when I enter the page, I don't want it to appear in the loading process. Any help appreciated.

```
.homepage
{
    width: 76px;
    height: 62px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 85%;
    right: 182px;
    background-image: url(anasayfa.png);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.homepage:hover
{
    top: 85.3%;
}


.scrollup
{
    width: 76px;
    height: 62px;
    background-image: url(yukaricik.png);
    position: fixed;
    top: 85%;
    right: 96px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.scrollup:hover
{
    top: 85.3%;
}

.nextpage {
    width: 76px;
    height: 62px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 85%;
    right: 10px;
    background-image: url(sonrakisayfa.png);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.nextpage:hover
{
    top: 85.3%;
}

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 13500) {
            $(".homepage").fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(".homepage").fadeOut();
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 13500){
            $(".scrollup").fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(".scrollup").fadeOut();
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".scrollup").click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 300);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 13500) {
            $(".nextpage").fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(".nextpage").fadeOut();
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: So why don't you just hide it with css, then unhide it in your javascript?

Comment: Use `display: none;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ugly but effective answer, add inline styling to the element.

```
<div style="display: none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The div to display none then fire fade in effect after the window is loaded

```
<div id="div" style="display:none;"></div>

$('window').load(function() {
  $('#div').fadeIn();
});
```